# How to prove or disprove that this integral is zero

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{m}^{\infty} \sqrt{x^2-m^2}\sin(xt) dx$$

I tried to associate a differential equation to the integral as a function of "m" and "t", but it got nowhere by that way. It doesn't mean that it can't be done, but it sure isn't easy. I tried a variable change of the style $ z ^ 2 = 1 / (x ^ 2-m ^ 2) $ after that separate the integral from 0 to 1 and from 1 to $\infty $ The one from 1 to $\infty$ converges. And then the one from 0 to 1 I tried to approximate the sin (z) ~ z but it is not true that $z=\sqrt(1 + m ^ 2x ^ 2)t/x $ approaches 0 when x is small, so way of saying that it diverges. So I ran out of ideas, help !!

Comment: What are the values of $m$ and $t$ you're working with? Because taking $m=0$ and $t=1$ leads to a [divergent integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2712471/695196).

Comment: m is particle mass so m>0 and t si time so t>0

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour for t---->∞ works for me. I found in some place that when t goes to ∞ sin oscilates very fast and then the only frecuency (w=omega) that survives is the lowest w=m there for the integral is sin(mt). But i'm not sure how legal is that

Comment: The integral surely diverges. BTW, use `\sqrt{...}`, not `\sqrt(...)` (here is why we see a "square root of the opening parenthesis"), and `\sin` instead of just `sin`.